# Tag [general] is so meta

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Trogdor? Please burninate the tag [general](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/general). No explanation necessary...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[general](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/general) has been removed.